# Retrieving data from a Composite type

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Iam in the processing of migrating a DB from Oracle to PostgreSQL. Oracle's stored functions allow nested proc's that share global data from the enclosing procedure. It seems PostgreSQL doesn't allow this, but might make for smaller procs in the long run.

To pass global data to a sub-process I thought I would wrap it up in a composite type.

```
CREATE TYPE sp_stickymsgin.t_std_data AS
(
    "pkAsset" bigint,
    "pkDevice" bigint,
    "glType" text,
    "pkCustomer" bigint,
    "pkMessageIn" bigint,
    "assetType" text
);
```

I can put data into the type and pass it into my nested procedure:

```
v_data := row(v_pkAsset,v_pkDevice,v_glType,v_pkCustomer,v_pkMessageIn,v_assetType)::sp_stickymsgin.t_std_data;
```

But I can't find any easy way to get it back out again and have resorted to the following, which seems a bit cumbersome.

```
select (in_data).* into v_pkAsset,v_pkDevice,v_glType,v_pkCustomer,v_pkMessageIn,v_assetType;
```

*Is there a better way to get the data out from the type or maybe a different method I haven't stumbled upon as yet?*

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
v_pkAsset = in_data."pkAsset";
v_pkDevice = in_data."pkDevice";
...
```

You can use it in a procedure. For example:

```
CREATE TYPE t_std_data AS
(
    "pkAsset" bigint,
    "pkDevice" bigint,
    "glType" text,
    "pkCustomer" bigint,
    "pkMessageIn" bigint,
    "assetType" text
);
CREATE TYPE

create procedure proc(param t_std_data)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
v bigint;
begin
 v = param."pkAsset";
 raise notice 'v=%',v;
end;
$$;
CREATE PROCEDURE

do
$$
declare 
in_data t_std_data;
begin
 in_data."pkAsset" = 1;
 call proc(in_data);
end;
$$;
psql:t.sql:33: NOTICE:  v=1
DO
```

Comment: I get the following error when I use v_pkAsset = in_data.pkAsset;  ERROR:  record "in_data" has no field "pkasset"

Comment: How is declared in_data ?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "sp_stickymsgin"."lp_decode_gl200_positions"("in_asseteventtype" varchar, "in_poscount" numeric, "in_data" "sp_stickymsgin"."t_std_data", "in_msgarray" text)

Comment: I have added the quotes you are using.

Comment: Even in the calling proc I can't do what you suggest which is v_pkAsset = in_data."pkAsset"; I get 'missing FROM-clause entry for table "in_data"'. I am missing something here?

Comment: I have added an example with a procedure. Looks like you are using some SELECT statement ? Post your code.